# Im Getting Errors From Terminal About My Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, terminal, theos

I have almost finished my code, but terminal is giving me the following errors:

```
Tweak.xm:149:15: error: unused variable 'settings' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"...
              ^
Tweak.xm:152:1: error: expected unqualified-id
if (settings) {
^
Tweak.xm:156:1: error: expected unqualified-id
if (lsSame) {
^
3 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.c8cb265e.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [CustomColr.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Here is my code:
http://pastie.org/10076062

Comment: Add some description here as well.

Comment: There is some code immediately above `-(void)setTextColor {` (line 163) that seems to be outside any method - Lines 152-159